# Woocommerce add to cart via ajax - 502 Bad gateway response

Tags: javascript, php, ajax, wordpress, woocommerce

I am adding items to cart via ajax that when if it reaches to a total of 10 items, the response that I get is a 502 bad gateway server error. Consider my example code:

```
    add_action('wp_ajax_nopriv_my_add_to_cart', 'my_add_to_cart');
    function my_add_to_cart() {
        for($i = 1; $i <= 10; $i++) {
            if( WC()->cart->add_to_cart(123, 1, null, null, ['some_unique_data']) ) {
                error_log('Successfully added to cart.');
            }
        }
        wp_send_json_success();
    }
```

I'm using postman to call and execute the function via ajax. This is the response I get:
[image]

But if I change the loop count to 9, I get a response of `200` by the `wp_send_json_success()` function.

This is the `debug.log` tail. As you can see It reached 10 counts of logging the message `Successfully added to cart` so this means that the 10 items are successfully added to cart without any error exceptions but it didn't reached the execution of `wp_send_json_success()`

[image]

What could be the problem here?

Here are some of my settings and other info.

```
upload_max_filesize = 64M
post_max_size = 256M
max_execution_time = 600
max_input_time = 300
memory_limit = 1024M

nginx/1.11.10
PHP version: 5.4.16

Wordpress: 4.9.1
Woocommerce: 3.2.5
```

### Update (2017-12-14)

Here's the screenshot of nginx logs:
[image]

### plesk.conf

[image]

Comment: Did you checked server logs? I just tested same function with over 60 products and didn't had any issues. To add multiple products at once I suggest you take a look at https://dsgnwrks.pro/snippets/woocommerce-allow-adding-multiple-products-to-the-cart-via-the-add-to-cart-query-string/

Comment: Hi @Dhaval, what server logs? Could you give me sample command that I can run to view those logs? Thank you for the link. Gonna check it now.

Comment: your URL is demo-site.com/wp-admin postmen, not wp-admin login

Comment: @solomonculaste Ideally they should be at `var/log/nginx/nginx_error.log` What I want you to see is if there are errors other than in WordPress, such as in nginx while sending back the response.

Comment: You've to tune `/etc/php/fpm/pool.d/www.conf` (or whatever file in that folder) file to set it to have more child instances

Comment: @DhavalShah I already included above the screenshot of the nginx logs. I think we still don't have hints.

Comment: @num8er Do you mean the pm.max_childrens? It currently have the value of 26. Do I have to modify and increase this value?

Comment: @solomonculaste can You add that pool.d file to Your question (at least `pm.*` params)?

Comment: @num8er If I run the command > find / -type d -name "pool.d" It shows only one result: /etc/sw-engine/pool.d and inside that it only contains the file plesk.conf. The screenshot of the values is included above.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After updating the Woocommerce plugin to its latest version (v3.3.3), this issue doesn't occur anymore.

Comment: I still got this issue with 9 items in a for-loop. Current WC version is 3.5.5